# In PsSetCreateThreadNotifyRoutine callback function stack of thread is empty

Tags: windows, callback, driver, windows-kernel

I want to read stack of a just created thread. In the callback function of PsSetCreateThreadNotifyRoutine() stack is still empty. Is there any other way to read what I want besides using pre/post features in ObCallback?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, because it's just a simple callback routine. Maybe Ex version has some information in it (haven't checked).

Have a look at: PsGetCurrentThreadStackBase. Better than nothing :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot about my question here :)
I have solved my problem this way: in the callback func I save the tid for next call of callback func by different thread - in this situation I'm sure the stack of the previuos thread is ready (yes, it isn't good, I know, but I didn't find any other ways)